# LINQ to Entities does not recognize deserialize method

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, devexpress

I'm trying to implement [Server mode](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/DataBindingToLargeDatabase) in one of  Devexpress Grid in my application.
Grid view expects queryable source, so I don't want to use ToList() or AsEnumerable(loads all the data into app memory). 
When I use AsQueryable I'm getting LINQ to Entities does  not recognize the method...

**Query details:**
One of the column(Definition) in the table is stored as JSON string. I understand that it is trying to find SQL equivalent for Deserialize method, Please suggest if you know any alternatives..

Below is the query.

```
var requestList = (from request in db.request_def
                    let requestDefinition=new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(request.Definition,typeof(RequestInfo))
                    let user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PRINCIPAL == requestDefinition.Principal)
                    let processingAccount =user.EMAIL
                    select new RequestModel
                    {
                        CreatedBy =  request.CreatedBy
                        CreatedOn = request.CreateOn,
                        Status = request.Status,
                        ProcessingAccount = processingAccount,

                    }).OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedOn).AsQueryable<RequestModel>();
```

Comment: How do you expect your database (or EF) to understand what `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(request.Definition,typeof(RequestInfo))` is supposed to do? Database has no idea about anything of the above.

Comment: I know that database doesn't understand the deserialize method, would like to know if there are alternatives like without deserialisation, some custom extension method we can write...

Comment: SQL server 2016 can work with json, so you might use raw sql query instead of EF, or create sql view with request.Description already parsed and use that instead of `request_def` table (as an example of alternative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be storing a JSON string in your database but you still want to "join" it to another table. Your options are probably limited to one of the following:

1. Drag the entire table into memory, deserialise and do your JOIN there. This would likely be horribly slow - don''t do this.
2. Move to a data store that is designed to be queried like this (i.e. MongodDB, DocumentDB etc.)
3. When you insert the JSON into your table, copy the value (i.e. `Principal`) into it's own column so you can do a classic SQL join, materialise the data in your code and *then* deserialise it.
4. If you are running SQL Server 2016 or newer then you should be able to run a raw SQL query against the database using [SQL Server JSON query](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/10/06/querying-json-documents-in-sql-server-2016-and-documentdb/)

Comment: We are running on SQL server 2012, so went with option 3 - creating separate column. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the ProcessingAccount field from the query to be able to execute it on the server side and retrieve data. Add the Definition field to the RequestModel, instead. Then, [add an unbound column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3770) in which you will manually load the ProcessingAccount data.

To do this, handle the [CustomUnboundColumnData](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcGridViewSettings_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event. In the event handler, obtain the Definition of the current record using the [ASPxGridColumnDataEventArgs.GetListSourceFieldValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridColumnDataEventArgs_GetListSourceFieldValuetopic) method, deserialise it, and load User from the database to obtain the ProcessingAccount.

To reduce the amount of database queries, it is better to retrieve Definition value of all records in the current page and load all related Users in batch. You can do this on the first call of the CustomUnboundColumnData event handler, and store the result in a local variable to use it on subsequent calls.